# Cassandra sstableloader - Connection refused

Tags: java, cassandra, connection, bulkloader

I am trying to bulk load a 4 node Cassandra 3.0.10 cluster with some data. I've successfully generated the SStables following the documentation, however it seems like I cannot get the sstableloader load them.

I get the following **java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused**

```
bin/sstableloader -v -d localhost test-data/output/si_test/messages/
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-1-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-10-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-11-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-12-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-13-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-14-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-15-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-16-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-17-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-18-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-19-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-2-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-20-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-21-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-22-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-23-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-24-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-25-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-26-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-27-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-28-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-29-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-3-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-30-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-31-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-32-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-33-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-34-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-35-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-36-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-37-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-38-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-39-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-4-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-40-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-41-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-42-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-43-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-44-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-45-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-46-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-47-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-48-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-49-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-5-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-50-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-51-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-52-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-53-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-54-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-55-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-56-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-57-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-58-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-59-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-6-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-60-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-61-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-7-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-8-big-Data.db /home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/test-data/output/si_test/messages/mc-9-big-Data.db to [localhost/127.0.0.1]
ERROR 14:46:24 [Stream #3d0c24e0-cc43-11e6-8c9f-615437259231] Streaming error occurred
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadConnectionFactory.createConnection(BulkLoadConnectionFactory.java:60) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.10.jar:3.0.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.createConnection(StreamSession.java:255) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.10.jar:3.0.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.initiate(ConnectionHandler.java:84) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.10.jar:3.0.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:242) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.10.jar:3.0.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$StreamSessionConnector.run(StreamCoordinator.java:212) [apache-cassandra-3.0.10.jar:3.0.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
progress: total: 100% 0  MB/s(avg: 0 MB/s)WARN  14:46:24 [Stream #3d0c24e0-cc43-11e6-8c9f-615437259231] Stream failed
Streaming to the following hosts failed:
[localhost/127.0.0.1]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:85)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:211)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:187)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:440)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.onError(StreamSession.java:540)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:248)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$StreamSessionConnector.run(StreamCoordinator.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The utility seems to connect to the cluster (**...Established connection to initial hosts..**), however I does not stream the data.

What I've tried so far to debug the issue:

- Dropped the target keyspace (and got a different error), created again via cqlsh
- I can telnet to each node of the cluster through ports 9042 and 7000
- Enabled thrift using `nodetool enablethrift`

---

**EDIT**

That's the output of `netstat -an | grep 7000`. The nodes have only one network interface and Cassandra is listening to it. It has also established connections with all the other nodes on port 7000.

```
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:7000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:7000        172.31.3.86:54348       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:7000        172.31.3.87:60661       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:53061       172.31.3.87:7000        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:7000        172.31.11.43:36984      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:51412       172.31.11.43:7000       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:54018       172.31.3.87:7000        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:7000        172.31.3.87:40667       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:34469       172.31.3.86:7000        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:43658       172.31.3.86:7000        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:7000        172.31.11.43:49487      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:40798       172.31.11.43:7000       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.3.88:7000        172.31.3.86:51537       ESTABLISHED
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Changing the initial host from 127.0.0.1 to the actual address of the node in the network results to a **com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException**:

```
bin/sstableloader -v -d 172.31.3.88 test-data/output/si_test/messages/
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /172.31.3.88:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/172.31.3.88] Cannot connect))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /172.31.3.88:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/172.31.3.88] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1424)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:163)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:334)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:309)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:251)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient.init(NativeSSTableLoaderClient.java:70)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:159)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:104)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved changing the **rpc_address** in the **cassandra.yaml** file from the default localhost to the actual address of each node.

Comment: This was needed for me too. I thought that rpc_address (aka native_transport_address) was only needed for communication between nodes, but I also needed to fix rpc_address for accessing my cluster from client apps.

Answer (score 4):

Thats it trying to connect to the storage port (7000). Its most likely binding to a different interface than `127.0.0.1`. You can check what its binding too with `netstat -an | grep 7000`. You may want to double check any firewall or iptable settings.

**UPDATE:** its not bound to 127.0.0.1 which is default but to 172.31.3.88. So call `sstableloader -v -d 172.31.3.88 test-data/output/si_test/messages/`

Also if you have ssl enabled (`server_encryption_options` in cassandra.yaml) you need to use 7001 and configure it to match. If you can telnet to 7000 its most likely not that though.

Worth noting that enabling thrift is not necessarily in 3.0.10. sstableloader no longer uses that (in older versions it was used to read the schema).

Comment: Thank you for the quick responde. SSL is disabled in the cassandra.yaml file. I've just added the output of the netstat command to the question.

Comment: added above, use `-d 172.31.3.88` in your call

Comment: I thought it would have automatically resolved the loopback interface to the actual address. However, it still does not stream the data, but instead results in a different error. I've updated the question.

Comment: Just solved changing the **rpc_address** from localhost to the actual address of each node.